# Is Signal Strength accurate?

Tags: android, signal-strength

So my question is to ask if Signal Strength is accurate ?

this is how I calculated my DBM

```
 public void onSignalStrengthsChanged(SignalStrength signalStrengths) {

        super.onSignalStrengthsChanged(signalStrengths);
        int SignalStrength_ASU= signalStrengths.getGsmSignalStrength();

        signalStrength= (2 * SignalStrength_ASU) - 113; // -> dBm
}
```

this is an example of the data I went out today and collect in a dense park
and to be honest is it possible to have a signal of 85? a positive signal?! BTW I am using note2

[image: example of signal data]

Comment: Documentation says  `Get the GSM Signal Strength, valid values are (0-31, 99) as defined in TS 27.007 8.5`  a 99 value would give you the 85 you see there. I assume 99 have some significant meaning, probably specified in TS 27.007 8.5. Whatever that is

Comment: They mention this (here's PDF):  http://www.etsi.org/deliver/etsi_ts/127000_127099/127007/08.05.00_60/ts_127007v080500p.pdf

Comment: how about is there another link that describe how many bars= -95
cause i know different provider have different calculation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The specification says this about signal strength values:

> 0 -113 dBm or less
>   1 -111 dBm
>   2...30 -109... -53 dBm
>   31 -51 dBm or greater
>   99 not known or not detectable

[source (page 81)](http://www.etsi.org/deliver/etsi_TS/127000_127099/127007/08.05.00_60/ts_127007v080500p.pdf)

The 99 value would givee you the calculated value of 85 that you see there. What to do when you get that value is up to you.

Comment: thanks so when it is undetectable does it mean ghost? Or is there any reason it is undetectable?

Comment: The specification does not say what could cause the signal strength to be ' not known or not detectable'. it is simply unknown.

Comment: okay just a side question i use my samsung S4 to collect the same data at the same position i had two different value of dBm so i concluded that different device have different dBm value?

Comment: Different devices with different receivers\antennas, would probably show some variations in signal strength yes.